# How to stop @CucumberContextConfiguration with @SpringBootTest from reloading application context between every test?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cucumber, spring-boot-test, cucumber-junit

I've got this problem where my application context is reloaded between every test. I'm wiring in my actual application with functional test properties, wiremock etc. to create a functional test environment. Tests have always run fine but now we've added several it's become painfully slow due to the spring application being re-run everytime. The io.cucumber versions I'm using in my pom for cucumber-spring, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit is 7.11.1.
My Functional Test runner is annotated like this:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = "classpath:functional/features",
    glue = {"com.iggroup.ds.functional.stepdefinitions"},
    monochrome = true,
    tags = "@FunctionalTest",
    plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report", "junit:target/cucumber-xml-report.xml"}
)
public class FunctionalTestRunner {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {
        prepareEnvironment();
    }

    private static void prepareEnvironment() {
        int applicationPort = SocketUtils.findAvailableTcpPort();
        System.setProperty("server.port", String.valueOf(applicationPort));
        System.setProperty("spring.active.profiles", "FUNCTIONAL_TEST");
        System.setProperty("spring.cloud.config.enabled", "false");
        System.setProperty("spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap", "false");
    }
}
```

Inside my glue package the Cucumber Configuration looks like this:

```
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 8089)
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = {
        ServiceApplication.class,
        RestClients.class
    },
    webEnvironment = DEFINED_PORT,
    properties = {
        "spring.profiles.active=FUNCTIONAL_TEST",
        "spring.cloud.config.enabled = false"
    }
)
public class FunctionalTestSpringCucumberConfiguration {
}
```

And lastly the application itself looks like this:

```
@EnableAsync
@EnableCaching
@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class ServiceApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I had read somewhere before that the presence of @MockBean was causing unexpected refreshes between context although I never found out as to why - but I have none defined. As far as I can tell across the articles I've been reading, this shouldn't refresh my context every time so wondering if there's any way I can force it not to rewire the ServiceApplication.class in between every scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 8089)
```

By using Wiremock on fixed port you are dirtying the application context. This means a new application context will be created for each test. [The code responsible for this](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/blob/main/spring-cloud-contract-wiremock/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/contract/wiremock/WireMockTestExecutionListener.java#L62-L69) prints a warning that you can see in your logs.

```java
if (portIsFixed(testContext)) {
    if (log.isWarnEnabled()) {
        log.warn("You've used fixed ports for WireMock setup - "
            + "will mark context as dirty. Please use random ports, as much "
            + "as possible. Your tests will be faster and more reliable and this "
            + "warning will go away");
    }
    testContext.markApplicationContextDirty(DirtiesContext.HierarchyMode.EXHAUSTIVE);
}
```

Comment: Incredible! For some reason this log has/is not appearing at all. Thank you so much for helping this has been annoying me for some days!

Comment: You should probably figure out why your logs aren't showing up.